# Android: How to trigger/show system SIM selection activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

For my app, I need to be able to show users which SIM they want to send SMS or call from. There is built-in system activity for this as shown in screen below:

[image]

That screen shows which SIM to use for calling. I would also like to trigger similar activity for user selection so they decide which SIM to send SMS from.

Question: How do I trigger that activity, for example on button/notification click? I don't know where it is located or what it is called. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I suspect is is under the Phone main activity but not sure how to call it.